# How to import a groups members using 'ldifde'?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2003, ldif

I have two domains. One production. One testing. There is no trust between the two.

I can import all user objects and group objects successfully using ldifde commands. When I attempt to also include group members in my export/import I can't seem to successfully import.

Here are the variations I have tried:

Attempt 1:

```
file format:
dn: CN=Group-name,OU=Groups,OU=Managed,DC=dev,DC=net
changetype: add
member: CN=USER1,OU=Users,OU=Managed,DC=dev,DC=net
member: CN=USER2,OU=Users,OU=Managed,DC=dev,DC=net

ldifde command used:
ldifde -i -k -f groupexp12072012-test.ldf -v

output:
Connecting to "DC"
Logging in as current user using SSPI
Importing directory from file "groupexp12072012-test.ldf"
Loading entries
1: CN=Group-name,OU=Groups,OU=Managed,DC=dev,DC=net

Add error on line 1: Object Class Violation
The server side error is "The object class attribute must be specified."
0 entries modified successfully.
An error has occurred in the program
No log files were written.  In order to generate a log file, please
specify the log file path via the -j option.
```

Attempt 2:
Added in the correct objectClass to my ldifde import file:

```
file format:
dn: CN=Group-name,OU=Groups,OU=Managed,DC=dev,DC=net
changetype: add
objectClass: top
objectClass: group
member: CN=USER1,OU=Users,OU=Managed,DC=dev,DC=net
member: CN=USER2,OU=Users,OU=Managed,DC=dev,DC=net

ldifde command used:
ldifde -i -k -f groupexp12072012-test.ldf -v

output:
Connecting to "DC"
Logging in as current user using SSPI
Importing directory from file "groupexp12072012-test.ldf"
Loading entries
1: CN=Group-name,OU=Groups,OU=Managed,DC=dev,DC=net
Entry already exists, entry skipped

0 entries modified successfully.

The command has completed successfully
```

Attempt 3:
Deleted the existing group object and used the same command and format as "Attempt 2":

```
Connecting to "DC"
Logging in as current user using SSPI
Importing directory from file "groupexp12072012-test.ldf"
Loading entries
1: CN=Group-name,OU=Groups,OU=Managed,DC=dev,DC=net
Object does not exist, entry skipped

0 entries modified successfully.
```

So I'm stuck. Apparently 'ldifde' can be used to import group members - all my colleagues say it has never worked but I stumble upon MS articles that say otherwise;
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/nl/winserverDS/thread/089a3f3b-617f-4c66-a3fc-be543d97a612

Then I stumble on "5. LDIFDE doesn’t support changing Group Membership. You can use CSVDE or ADDUSERS.exe or DStools for Windows 2003 Editions." here:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555634

Am I going crazy for no reason - will I ever succeed using 'ldifde'?

**edit:** Yes, I was going crazy for no reason. One of my targeted users was actually in a different OU I was specifying for 'ldifde'. Because of this, 'ldifde' would just give up and not add any members to the group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to add users to an existing group (`ldifde -i -k -f AddGrpMember.ldf -v`
):

```
dn: CN=MonGrpSec,OU=MonOu,DC=dom,DC=fr
changeType: Modify
add: member
member: CN=jblanc,OU=MonOu,DC=dom,DC=fr
member: CN=Jean Paul Blanc,OU=MonOu,DC=dom,DC=fr
-
```

Here is a way to create a new group with members (`ldifde -i -k -f NewGrpWithMember.ldf -v`
):

```
dn: CN=NewGrpSec,OU=MonOu,DC=dom,DC=fr
changeType: Add
objectClass: top
objectClass: group
CN: NewGrpSec
member: CN=jblanc,OU=MonOu,DC=dom,DC=fr
member: CN=Jean Paul Blanc,OU=MonOu,DC=dom,DC=fr
```

Comment: I've accepted this answer as its fundamentally correct and helped me determine the actual problem. The actual problem? One of my targeted users was in a different OU in the target domain and helpfully 'ldifde' would just throw up its arms and call it quits.

Answer (score 0):

ldifde import of group members fails if the group members do not exist, or the dn in the file does not match the dn of the target group.

For a few important groups in my test domain, I word to replace "member:" with the entire header to modify a group.  That way any individual group member doesn't halt the rest of the group members from importing.

Simple find and replace
find: member:
replace with: -^p^pdn:CN=[groupname],OU=[ou name],OU=Domain Users,DC=TEST,DC=ORG^pchangetype: modify^padd:member^pmember:

Basically, add a "-" followed by a blank line, and then the header lines.