# Save the current state of an active directory

Tags: unit-testing, junit, active-directory, connection, state

I want to save the states of various databases for a reliable Unit-Testing.

SQL-Databases are easy, I just make a dump-file and can recreate my database from scratch every time I run my tests. My question is, can I do the same with an active directory? Can I recreate the state of an active directory with a script or do I have to save the database as an instance (for example a text file) and just use it as a "fake" active directory (just an Object and not a Connection)

What approaches are useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Active Directory can also be exported and restored as [LDIF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LDAP_Data_Interchange_Format) using [`LDIFDE`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555636). For example, see [How to import a groups members using 'ldifde'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11465364/how-to-import-a-groups-members-using-ldifde) for a case of adding data.

However, unless you're specifically writing and testing code that uses Active Directory, mocking it out, either in your code or with a lightweight LDAP server, will better isolate your tests and make them run faster ([How to fake Active Directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12354107/how-to-fake-active-directory)).